# Record with Array of itself in Delphi

Tags: delphi, data-structures, structure, record

Does anyone know how to do something like this?

```
type TFileRecord = record
    Name: String;
    CreationTimeStamp: DWORD;
    Subfiles: Array of TFileRecord;
end;
```

I am using Delphi 10.4.

Comment: Samuel Andrade: I'm afraid it is hard to tell what exactly you are asking. If you copy this code into a Delphi program or unit and press the Compile button, it will compile, and it will work as expected.

Comment: I assume the upvoters understand what the OP is asking. Could you please explain to me?

Comment: The only explanation that makes sense is that the actual code has a fixed length array .......

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Sympathy votes is more likely explanation

Comment: Indeed. @Samuel, you might want to read about the difference between [static arrays](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Static_Arrays) and [dynamic arrays](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Arrays) and their internal representations [1](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Internal_Data_Formats_(Delphi)#Static_Array_Types), [2](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Internal_Data_Formats_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Array_Types). In short, a static array is a value type while...

Comment: ...a dynamic array is a reference type (merely a pointer to a dynamic array heap object). So while your code above, which uses a dynamic array, works well (`Subfiles` is merely a 32-bit or 64-bit pointer.), it is theoretically impossible to replace it with a static array. Because if you think about it, you will realise that that would make the size of `TFileRecord` infinite!

Comment: Actually, i wish to make a mutual reference. I editted the question.

Comment: @SamuelAndrade, I rolled back the question, since it entirely changes the question. You should rather ask a new question.

Comment: I upvoted the question (after seeing it having downvotes), since, even though the question was a bit poorly worded (it really should have asked "Is this a valid construct?"), it was pretty obvious that "is this valid?" was the real question, and that was an interesting one.

Comment: In D2007 it *doesn't* compile. @SamuelAndrade, you should add your Delphi version as a tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my Delphi 10.4.1 it is certainly possible to have that kind of declaration:

```
unit TestUnit;

interface

type
  TFileRecord = record
    Name: String;
    CreationTimeStamp: Cardinal; //DWORD;
    Subfiles: Array of TFileRecord;
  end;

Procedure TestTFR;

implementation

Procedure TestTFR;
var
  TFR : TFileRecord;
begin
  SetLength(TFR.SubFiles,2);
  SetLength(TFR.Subfiles[0].Subfiles,2);
end;    

end.
```

This feature was introduced in Delphi 2009.
Before that, the compiler complained about ***TFileRecord is not yet completely defined***.

As discussed in comments, the size of a dynamic array can only be the size of a pointer, which the compiler architects realised at that time. Knowing that, the finalization of the type declaration is of no importance for the single pass compiler.

Comment: Compiles fine in Delphi XE7 as well.

Comment: Interestingly this works only in case when you have an object (could be either record or class) that contains dynamic array of objects of the same type. But when you try to declare objects that has same object type as field or contains static array of same typed objects Delphi spews out an error that type isn't yet completely defined.

Comment: I'm guessing compiler is smart enough to know that in case of dynamic array objects contained in array will be stored in their own memory blocks so their size isn't important at the creation of object that contains such dynamic array. But if such objects would be defined as fields or within a fixed size array they might be stored within the same memory block as the object that contains them. in such case you do need to know the size and structure of that object in advance.

Comment: PS: Does anybody know of a good article or book which would explain more detail of how Delphi memory manager stores different objects. I think this could be an interesting read. And yes I know that FastMM is an open source but I doubt my knowledge of Delphi is good enough to understand its internals regarding this by just looking through its source code.

Comment: @SilverWarior: If a record type contains a field of its own type, you get an infinitely sized record, a theoretical concept that is impossible to realise. And static arrays are value types, so `array[0..3] of X` is the same thing as `record dummy1, dummy2, dummy3, dummy4: X end` except for padding. Hence, if a record type contains a field of type static array of the record itself, you again get this infinite recursion and an impossible construction. All you need to know about internal data formats is found at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Internal_Data_Formats_(Delphi).

Comment: I often refer to that page in SO answers, particularly when it comes to dynamic arrays and (long) strings.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand That is a very helpful part of documentation that for some reason I haven't ran into till now. I have added it to my bookmarks as it will definitely come in handy. Thanks.